# How are functions without variable declarations in Javascript possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this library called [react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider) to implement a multi slider for a mobile application using React Native.

I was going through the example in the repository and found something odd that works somehow.

There are functions without any variable declaration [in the code](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider/blob/56325ec79bc98dcb6db8fc1b2782951e2b6b2e4f/examples/Basic/App.js#L26).

```
const [multiSliderValue, setMultiSliderValue] = React.useState([3, 7]);
const [sliderOneChanging, setSliderOneChanging] = React.useState(false);

sliderOneValuesChangeFinish = () => setSliderOneChanging(false);

multiSliderValuesChange = values => setMultiSliderValue(values);
```

I initially thought this was a mistake but I used the code in my application and it works without any runtime errors and these "functions" work as intended.

For example, `multiSliderValuesChange` sets the values that are passed into it to `setMultiSliderValues()` and when I log the values of `multiSliderValue` it does match the values on the slider.

`multiSliderValuesChange` is passed in as a prop to `onValuesChange` which is a callback to update the values when they change, [as per the documentation](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider#partial-report-of-the-props).

```
<MultiSlider
          values={[multiSliderValue[0], multiSliderValue[1]]}
          sliderLength={250}
          onValuesChange={multiSliderValuesChange}
          min={0}
          max={10}
          step={1}
          allowOverlap
          snapped
          customLabel={CustomLabel}
        />
```

I went into the [type definitions file](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider/blob/56325ec79bc98dcb6db8fc1b2782951e2b6b2e4f/index.d.ts#L34) of the `MultiSlider` component and `onValuesChange` takes as input an array of numbers and returns nothing:

```
onValuesChange?: (values: number[]) => void;
```

But I still do not understand how it works without any variable declarations such as `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: It works, it's just really sloppy code. They should fix it.

Comment: Without `let`, `const` or `var` the variable will be defined on the closest scope where it already exists or the global scope (`window` in a browser). This can lead to issues if multiple instances of the code are used at the same time (overwriting the variable) or if two separate sections of code use the same variable name omitting `let`, `const` and `var`.